# Using instanceof for custom object without new keyword in Javascript

Tags: javascript

I have a factory function that is supposed to return function to create instances of the object. Quite simplified it looks like this.

```
var Factory = function() {
  var factoryPrototype = {};
  var TypeFunction = function() {
    return Object.create(factoryPrototype);
  };
  return TypeFunction;
};
```

Then I am able to simply call `Factory()` to get the function that I can use for referencing that particular type.

Question is, how could I allow `instanceof` operator for this?

```
var Mytype = Factory();
console.log(MyType instanceof Factory);
```

From my understanding that operator is comparing `MyType.__proto__` vs `Factory.prototype`. I can manage first part like this.

```
Object.setPrototypeOf(TypeFunction, Factory);
```

It goes without error and function itself is working correctly. Second part is a failure point. I can do just `Factory.prototype = Factory`, but that seems so dirty I would rather not... Is there some other "nicer" way?

Either way, after using that last call, I can then use `Factory.isPrototypeOf(MyType)` which works correctly and it's probably only *clean* way now...

What do you think about modifying prototype chain of function? Could there be some side effects I don't see?

### Update:

Based on @SLaks solution I went even more deep and applied the pattern to the actual instances too.. http://jsfiddle.net/FredyCr/egbfyood/1/

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/SLaks/mhwg6qgc/1/

Comment: @SLaks I have extended your solution and applied to those inner instances too. Works like magic :) http://jsfiddle.net/FredyCr/pap0g2wp/1/

Comment: You missed the `constructor` property.  http://blog.slaks.net/2013-09-03/traditional-inheritance-in-javascript/

Comment: Also, `factoryPrototype` should not inherit `Function.prototype`, since it isn't for a function.  You might as well just use `TypeFunction.prototype`, so that callers can modify it like a normal ctor.

Comment: Nice blog post there, but I am probably missing point. Why do I need constructor property exactly? It's only fancy stuff without real use.

Comment: As of the `factoryPrototype`, you are right, I wasn't thinking clear. This works well too... http://jsfiddle.net/FredyCr/egbfyood/1/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to make your new function inherit from Factory:

```
Object.setPrototypeOf(TypeFunction, Factory.prototype);
```

However, this will lose everything you inherit from `Function.prototype`, such as `call` and `bind`.

Therefore, you also need to make sure that `Factory.prototype` includes them:

```
Factory.prototype = Object.create(Function.prototype);
```